# Field of an Uniformly Charged Infinite Plane Sheet

Tags: electrostatics, electric-fields, charge, singularities, coulombs-law

Let's consider two cases:

1. Let's say that we have two positive point charges. If we get those charges together very very very close to each other, the repulsive force goes to infinity between those ones. (This fact is so clear to me-according to coulomb's law).
2. Now lets say that we have a positive point charge and an Uniformly positively Charged Infinite Plane Sheet. If we get this point charge closer and closer to this sheet, It should still give us infinite repulsive force.

I am really frustrated with the second case, why it does not give us infinite repulsive force when we get this point charge closer and closer to this sheet. Please give me guys a little bit intuition what's going on here?

Comment: In the context of an **infinite** sheet what does *very, very close* mean?

Comment: *"Let's discuss..."* This is not really a discussion forum, it is a question and answer forum. The idea is that you pose a single, clear, answerable question and then we answer it. Some guidance is posted here: https://physics.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask

Comment: For discussion you can go here: https://chat.stackexchange.com/?tab=site&host=physics.stackexchange.com

Comment: OP is asking a question.

Comment: I don't want to discuss, I am asking a question. I said this to tell you what my question is about

Comment: There is no reason to close this question. OP is focusing on one problem only, namely why the force doesn't increase as a charge is brought closer to the sheet.  OP is a new contributor and this action hardly serves as a welcome to Physics SE.

Comment: I agree with @Not_Einstein that this is not unfocused, and it is an intuitively interesting conceptual question. In mathematics, an infinite plane is made up of infinite points (or infinite lines), so it is very understandable that it is confusing why a point charge (and an infinite line charge) can produce an infinite force on a point charge but an infinite charge sheet cannot.

Comment: The post **literally** starts with the words "Let's discuss two cases..." If OP doesn't want a discussion then OP should consider changing the words "Let's discuss two cases..." to something else like "Consider two cases..."

Comment: Providing comments and answers can be considered as comprising a "discussion." From Merriam-Webster dictionary: Discuss - "to investigate by reasoning or argument, to present in detail for examination or consideration."

Comment: For one thing, you are getting closer and closer to less and less of the charge. There is a charge-per-unit-area distribution, not a charge-at-this-point.

Comment: @Not_Einstein Are you trying to explain the meaning of the word "discuss?" Its meaning is well known. Yes, you can massage many different things to fit under the general heading of "discussion." But nevertheless, this website is not a discussion forum. So what does **that** mean? Does it mean that this website is not a place for comments or answers? No, it does not. So what is your point?

Comment: From the help: *"If your motivation for asking the question is “I would like to participate in a discussion about ______”, then you should not be asking here. However, if your motivation is “I would like others to explain ______ to me”, then you are probably OK. (Discussions are of course welcome in our real time web chat.)"*

Comment: @hft  If OP just said let's discuss a point charge near an infinite charged sheet, then I'd agree but he specifically asked a question, as he is supposed to do. So if he started his post by saying let's consider two cases instead of let's discuss two cases, you would not have objected? Seems like a lot of emphasis put on the choice of one word.

Comment: @Not_Einstein Yes, it is a lot of emphasis on one word, but it is an important word. Also, the only question I see that OP actually asked was: *"Please give me guys a little bit intuition what's going on here?"* Which is not exactly a focused question. I understand that OP clarified in the comments that OP doesn't want to discuss. But it would be even more clear if OP edited the question to remove the word "discuss."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppose the point charge is some distance away from the sheet. The force due to a small area dA directly below the charge is perpendicular to the sheet. For an area other than dA, there is a component of force parallel and perpendicular to the sheet, but there is another area on the other side of dA such that its horizontal component of force cancels that of the other area so the net force is perpendicular to the sheet (which we know by symmetry must be the case).

Now as we move the charge closer and closer to the sheet, the force due to areas on either side of dA have larger and larger horizontal components, so less contributions to the net force on the charge. This counteracts the increase in force due to the charge being closer to dA.

Taken to the limit extremely close to the sheet, only an infinitesimal surface charge is contributing to the force on the point charge as explained by @Albertus Magnus. The force depends inversely on the distance to dA but the effective area dA contributing to the force has units of distance squared and is decreasing, the net result is a finite force on the point charge, hence a finite electric field.

Comment: Excellent "intuitive" explanation given here. Well articulated!

Comment: I'm really happy that you understood what my question is about. But I still don't understand.
I don't understand this statement: _"so less contributions to the net force on the charge"_.  - net force is a horizontal component of the force, rigtht? 
 this statement either: _"This counteracts the increase in force due to the charge being closer to dA."_  - how can the force of the side areas of dA can counteract _"the increase in force due to the charge being closer to dA."_

Comment: Areas of the sheet not directly underneath the charge contribute with force components parallel and perpendicular to the sheet. As the charge gets closer, the parallel components greatly outweigh the perpendicular ones, the latter being the only ones that count as we know from symmetry. So those other areas are contributing less to the net force, while the contribution from the area directly below is increasing due to the inverse square law. As we know the force is independent of distance, these two effects - less contribution from away areas and more from directly below must cancel out,

Comment: It's not counteracting the force, it's that the net force is due to all areas on the sheet. As the charge is brought closer, one contribution - from directly below - is increasing while another contribution - other areas - is decreasing keeping the sum constant,

Comment: I have undestood what you have said in this statement, I have gotten that this is the case: "those other areas are contributing less to the net force, while the contribution from the area directly below is increasing due to the inverse square law". but I cant get this: If the contribution from the area directly below is increasing as the charge is brought closer, then when we get the charge closer and closer, the contribution must go to infinity. so why don't we get infinite repulsive force?

Comment: What I'm calling the area "directly below" is not a fixed area. It's the area element that is contributing a force on the charge that is more or less perpendicular to the sheet. As the charge gets closer to the sheet, the edges of that area are now contributing forces that are less perpendicular (and more parallel) to the sheet. So what we want to consider as "directly below" now has to be a smaller area hence a smaller amount of charge. That counteracts the effect of the closer distance.

Comment: you say: _"**That** counteracts the effect of the closer distance"_. What is the **That**. Is it _"directly below" now has to be a smaller area_? . Then why a point charge can produce an infinite force on a point charge?

Comment: The "that" is the fact that there's a surface charge therefore when considering a smaller area it contains less charge. I don't know what to say about an "infinite force." Obviously this is not possible in the real world as charges always have some non-zero size so when they come together (when you might consider there should be an infinite force) their centers are actually a finite distance apart. We're probably venturing into the world of quantum mechanics so perhaps someone else could comment.

Answer (score 2):

If you integrate Coulomb's law over the entire infinite sheet you find that the electric field is given by: $$ E(\vec r)={1\over 4\pi\epsilon_0}\int_S {\vec r-\vec r^\prime\over |\vec r-\vec r^\prime |^3}\cdot \vec n\; dS={\sigma\over 2{\epsilon}_0}.$$ Since the answer is free of $\vec r$ the electric field is the same at all points exterior to the sheet, thus even if you are arbitrarily close to the surface the magnitude of the force will still have the value ${\sigma\over 2\epsilon_0}$. An intuitive reason for this is that with any extended charge distribution, the test charge no longer sees individual point charges, but rather the superposition field of infinitesimal charge density elements summed over in the integral. Thus, you cannot say, there is a point charge directly beneath my test charge, so as I get closer to the body it should feel an ever increasing force. The test charge does not see point charges, but rather, infinitesimal elements of charge $dq=\rho(\vec r^\prime)dA$.

In fact, if you get close enough to the surface of any charge distribution, infinite or not, the particulars of geometry can be ignored and the charge distribution produces a field that looks much like that of the infinite plane, i.e. $|\vec E|={\sigma\over \epsilon_0}$. It is thus not surprising that an infinite plane just looks like an infinite plane no matter no close you get, hence, what is the real meaning of getting close to an infinite plane charge density.

Comment: please, could you provide a little bit geometric visualisation of what the letters in your equations stand for?

Comment: @Emzar Chichoevi $\vec r$ is the position at which the field is calculated, $\vec r^\prime$ is the integration variable, i.e. points on the charge density (plane), $\vec n$ is the normal to charged plane. $\vec n$ is not needed, however, I use it so that I get the magnitude $E(\vec r)$ as opposed to $\vec E(\vec r)$ of the field. $S$ is the charged plane, $dS$ the differential element of surface area. Finally, $\sigma$ is the charge density.